# I need to display contents at the top of the page rather than the bottom

Tags: php, html, post

How can I display the message for $myGame variable after a post?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      $myGame = "";
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["myGame"])) {
          $myGame = "";
        } else {
          $myGame = test_input($_POST["myGame"]);
        }
      }
      function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        return $data;
      }
    ?>

    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <?php echo $myGame;?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
    </form>

    <?php
      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $myGame = "Does this message display after post?";
        $_POST['myGame'] = $myGame;
      }
    ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you go to this page http://universitychess.com/creategame.php
and post, then scroll to the bottom, it shows the new url. I need it at the top of the page, but $myGame doesn't display it.

Comment: what kind of a title is "George is gettin upset" ? The title needs to be descriptive for the question/problem. What you used won't help in a search.

Comment: `$myGame = "Does this message display after post?";
    $_POST['myGame'] = $myGame;` and why are you doing that? That doesn't make sense. The POST array should be assigned to a variable, not the other way around.

Comment: The $myGames variable is holding the url to the web page that script creates on post. I tried a php redirect, but it failed. This page creates another web page http://universitychess.com/creategame.php

Comment: Seriously, though, it looks like you're expecting your form to post a value for `myGame`, but I don't see a form input with that name.

Comment: Funk, I did't know I was supposed to close issues. I thought the system did it automatically.

Comment: Nope; you need to give that checkmark a slight "tick" ;-)

Comment: why was my comment deleted? I didn't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I just want to set and display the $myGame data after posting. How does your message get deleted Funk?

Comment: someone flagged it, which I don't know why. I was not disrespectful or impolite.

Comment: I didn't flag any comments here, fwiw.

Comment: in any case, use error reporting with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see what you get back. @user1854438

Comment: @Don'tPanic You never entered my mind. Edit: I don't care who, it's the "why".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well, just thought I should mention it since I'm the only other one who's said anything here. ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic no worries. Just because it's you and I, doesn't mean there isn't anyone else here, and probably eyeballing possible solutions so they could make it their own. How many times have we seen that? Heh... right ;-) countless. So they decided; hey.. I'll flag this... meh. I know you're cool ;-)

Comment: I didn't see any errors. After posting, if you scroll down to the bottom of the page, it will show the new url. That is what I want displayed at the top of the page.

Comment: Wow, people really can't take a joke. No one watches Seinfeld anymore?

Comment: @user1854438 *"I want displayed at the top of the page"* - ooOOOOooohhh, so now we know what this is really about. Why didn't you put that in your question from the beginning? This was more about "location", an important detail here.

Comment: @user1854438 heh, yeah I loved that show!!! But... again, the title should be descriptive of the question here, notice the upvotes on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581817/george-is-gettin-upset#comment86171725_49581817) about it?

Comment: Funk, because the issue is that $myGame isn't displaying the info. lol. I'll update the question so it is more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

If your script calls the same page you can leave `action` parameter empty (`action=""`)

**Secondly**

You want to get `$_POST["myGame"]` variable but there is no input with `myGame` name.

Here is how I would do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body> 
<?php
$myGame = "";

if (isset($_POST))) {

  if (!empty($_POST["myGame"])) {
    $myGame = test_input($_POST["myGame"]);
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  return $data;
}

?>

<h2>TITLE</h2>

<?php echo $myGame;?>

<form method="post" action="">  
  <input type="text" name="myGame">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"> 
</form>
```

**Additional information**

You should not get `$_POST` values directly.

It is better to do it this way: `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'myGame')` instead of `$_POST['myGame']`

[filter_input](http://www.php.net/filter_input)